# Python's try - except not working as expected

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, exception

I'm having some trouble understanding how exceptions work exactly in Python.

In the code below, `someClass` is initialized and the `run_engine()` method is called upon it. 
The `run_engine()` method spawns various threads and one of those threads is a 'data source' thread. The data source thread queries a database for a specific set of data, and the database will in its turn start to stream (sub-pub mechanism) the queried dataset. When the completedata set is transmitted to my Python application, the database will then close the connection with the data source thread to indicate that the stream has ended and other actions may take place. This is where the trouble starts.

In the `_fetch_data()` method below I'm catching the `QReaderException` (the one that is raised when the db disconnects) and raise a custom one (`ServiceExitException`) in order to do some final actions in the main thread.

For some reason, it prints the stacktrace of both exceptions (so the `QReaderException` seems to be catched, but does not go by silently.

Why is this happening? Does it have something todo with the threaded nature of my application?

Thanks!

```
# This method belongs to the data source thread
def _fetch_data(self):
    while not self.stopped():
        try:
            message = self.connections[self.port].receive(data_only=False, raw=False)  # retrieve entire message
            if message.type != MessageType.ASYNC:
                raise UnexpectedMessageTypeException('Unexpected message, expected message of type: ASYNC')
            if isinstance(message.data, list):
                return message

        except (QReaderException, UnexpectedMessageTypeException) as e:
            # this block seems to be executed
            raise ServiceExitException()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    someClass = SomeClass()

    try:
        someClass.run_engine()
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)

    except ServiceExitException as e:
        someClass.stop_engine()
        someClass.join()
        someClass.store_data()
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a line in between saying something like

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

You could say Python does not regard the first exception as handled until the except block is over. Therefore they are both considered unhandled and the tracebacks are combined into one.

Maybe it becomes a little clearer if you use

```
raise ServiceExitException() from e
```

Then the message in between tracebacks becomes

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

But AFAIK that's as far as you can go with that sort of Exception redirection. The easiest thing I guess would be to just leave away the custom `ServiceExitException` and just `except:` everything in you main code. Or even better, use a `try: .. finally: ..` construct, which avoids annoying hints from tools like pylint that you shouldn't do broad all-catching `except`s.